# How to achieve this effect using html5/css3

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas

How to achieve this effect using html5/css3: https://i.stack.imgur.com/juNGo.jpg

The idea is to move those rays clockwise. On the images you can see a slightly movement. It would be interesting to achieve the effect without using external images.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start off by modifying this codepen: http://codepen.io/akashnimare/pen/sjmbB

Comment: Amazing thanks!!!! cant upvote you because my reputation is to low. css3 animations are awesome!!!